# JupyterLab not loading environment variables

Tags: jupyter-notebook, anaconda, jupyter-lab

I have some passwords and such set in my bash_profile that I want to be able to access from within Jupyter notebooks. They are successfully loaded whenever I use just a Jupyter notebook, but not when I use JupyterLab.

I am using Anaconda, and I double checked that the location of my JupyterLab and JupyterNotebook's are the same using which jupyter/jupyter-lab/jupyter-notebook and they do all point to my Anaconda bin directory. I also made sure the anaconda3/bin directory is in my bash profile and that the conda environment was activated.

Whenever I run os.environ in a notebook using Lab versus just a plain notebook I expect the same output, however the Lab instance does not load anything I have manually added to my profile while a plain notebook does.

Comment: did you try restarting jupyterLab after doing ```source bash_profile``` after adding the variables to the bash_profile file?

Comment: yes, that is typically the first thing I do after adding anything to my profile

Comment: In the event anyone else experiences this issue, it was due to defaulting to my local copy of Jupyter Lab (installed via Anaconda), so i completely uninstalled Conda and now all is good. Strange, I was under the impression that Docker would use a completely different (fresh) copy of Jupyter Lab